# Date.ValueOf(TimeStamp) Changes TIme of Original DateTime Field. I'm Confused Why?

Tags: apex, date, datetime

I've noted very strange behaviour in some Apex code I'm running.
If I use the Date.ValueOf() function on a datetime. If I then print out the DateTime afterwards the hour/minutes of it have changed to 03:00.

The following code is an example which causes this.

```
DateTime test1 = System.Now();
System.debug('Hello Test1 BeforeDateValueOf ' + test1);
Date test1Date = Date.ValueOf(test1);
System.debug('Hello Test1 ' + test1);
```

Prints out the following:

> 16:19:03:002 USER_DEBUG [2]|DEBUG|Hello Test1 BeforeDateValueOf  2018-07-20 15:19:03 
>   16:19:03:064 USER_DEBUG [4]|DEBUG|Hello Test1  2018-07-20 03:00:00

Why is the time of `test1` variable has changed? Surely `test1Date` is treated separately?

Comment: Why not just use `test1.date()`?

Comment: Is your timezone BST(UTC+1) ?

Comment: Why are you looking at Time in an object whichw as supposed to store only DATE properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So your answer lies in [Date.ValueOf](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm) documentation.

> In API version 33.0 or earlier, if you call Date.valueOf with an
>   object that represents a Datetime, the method returns a Date value
>   that contains the hours, minutes, and seconds. In version 34.0 and
>   later, Date.valueOf converts the object to a valid Date without the
>   time information. To convert a variable of type Datetime to a Date,
>   use the Datetime.date method.

We are not supposed to get the time-information in valueOf() in the recent version of API's, thus using it to get time would provide you inconsistent results. The value in timezone we get is for handling the timzone.

Thus your code can use date(); method instead

```
DateTime test1 = System.Now();
System.debug('Hello Test1 BeforeDateValueOf ' + test1);
Date test1Date = test1.date();
System.debug('Hello Test1 ' + test1);
```

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful and good to know going forward.